# Sigma algebra on the index set in the definition of a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Suppose that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a filtered probability space with totally ordered index set $T$. A stopping time is a random variable $\tau: \Omega \to T$ (e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time). In order to parse this requirement, we require that $T$ is endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra. In typical cases where $T$ is $\mathbb{N}$ or $[0, \infty)$, I can understand that the implied $\sigma$-algebra is the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but I am wondering what the $\sigma$-algebra is supposed to be if $T$ is an arbitrary totally ordered set.

My hypothesis is that we could just endow $T$ with the order topology and then make use of the associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Is this correct? Do we have a choice of $\sigma$-algebras on $T$ for which $\tau$ is still considered a stopping time?

Comment: No sigma algebra on $T$ is required to define a stopping time.

Comment: So the wikipedia should instead say that a stopping time is merely a function $\tau: \Omega \to T$ such that $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t \in T$?

Comment: Yes, that is the usual definition of a stopping time.

Comment: Oh ok. All of the other sources I looked at also used the term 'random variable' when defining a stopping time so it seemed like it really was part of the definition. (e.g. http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-ST.pdf and http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/ap.pdf and https://ece.iisc.ac.in/~parimal/2020/spqt/lecture-04.pdf)

Comment: The defining condition $\{\tau\le t\}\in \mathcal F_t$ implies that $\tau$ is measurable if you endow $T$ with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $\{s\in T: s\le t\}$.

Comment: Yep so in other words, if we understand that $T$ is endowed with the order topology (or anything weaker), then the choice of 'function' or 'random variable' is irrelevant.